# Jar File beans not imported to the Maven project it is used

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, jar

I created a Maven project which is packages as a Jar file. I used the Jar file to build a UI in another Maven project. But when I create beans of Classes in Jar file I end up getting a null pointer exception for the variables those classes have. But when I wire the bean with the necessary values and beans, I can use the classes present in the Jar file. Is there a way such that I could just create a bean of the class present in the Jar file without wiring the required values and beans?

NOTE: I have wired the required beans and values for the classes in the Jar file in the Jar files Maven project. Shouldn't the UI project be taking values from that wiring made in the Jar file project.

[image]

Comment: Please provide the pom file to analyse it better.

Comment: It seems you're mixing a lot of things. Based on tags you use Spring, so I assume your beans use @Autowired annotation on injection points, but fields do not get populated by Spring? Do you use Spring in UI? What UI framework do you use, if any? How do you create those beans?

Comment: This might be of interest: https://blog.frankel.ch/optional-dependencies-in-spring. It is describing how you can do optional dependencies in spring.